# How can I fight the gods?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I'm always getting to level 20, and then I go up to the gods, getting crushed.

So what am I doing wrong? Why can't I survive the Gods on the max level?

Comment: Equipment, probably.

Comment: Yeah, but where do I get equipment to stand a chance?

Comment: I didn't answer because I _lack_ a full answer. :)

Comment: Survival tip orthogonal to the answers: Hot-key nexus to something other than the default. I use F. If you go below 50% health, press it. Don't risk all your investment in your character for that def pot sitting next to those three medusa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a beginner to the game, I found the easiest class to play for farming gods was a Priest.

It sounds a bit odd, but priests use the longest range main weapon in the game (wands), and they can heal themselves. So you can just sit back and shoot gods off the screen. When you take some damage, pop your heal spell.

In addition to that, Priests have great natural speed, so avoiding damage is easier than with a slower character.

Answer (score 3):

Necromancer is also a good class for fighting gods. They can heal themselves by draining health from enemies and have good range and damage. They are a very forgiving class to play and probably your best bet for surviving in the godlands.

Also try to avoid as many bullets as possible, gods deal a lot more damage than the usual enemies. Even with maximized defense they are still dangerous. You can take a couple of hits as a level 10

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, to fight Gods, you're going to need to play a long-ranged character, and get better at the game.  Know how to use your abilities optimally, avoid bullets, and get better gear.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is be a knight and have high speed and dexterity equipment if possible.

If you want the best class to make survival more probable, you probably want to use a class that can use a staff and have high speed to dodge attacks.

Comment: How do you use a staff on a knight?

Answer (score -1):

I use a sorcerer and spam the space key and shoot people off the screen - and it's gg.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the priest for a start then level up to archer with archer is long range and space is good for the big ones